# JSP files not rendering when deploying spring boot jar in appengine standard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, java-17

Hi I want to run spring boot application with jsp files as view and deploy it in google appengine standard. The issue is that jsp files are not getting rendered while i deploy the jar but working locally. I am using java 17.I am using spring boot 3.1.1 with jetty. I am using intellij maven to package the whole application into a jar. This jar is running locally but not rendering the jsp pages when deployed to appengine standard using gcloud app deploy command.

This is my pom.xml:-

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- Exclude Tomcat so that it doesn&amp;#39;t conflict w/ Jetty server -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>




    </build>
```

This is my app.yaml in src/main/appengine

```
runtime: java17
```

This is my appengine-web.xml in webapp/WEB-INF/

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<runtime>java17</runtime>
<instance-class>B1</instance-class>
<manual-scaling>
    <instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```